# openssl req: -days <days> will not accept argument in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, openssl

I am testing a bash shell script function to automate generating a root CA certificate using `openssl` ([version 1.0.2](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl-req.html)). when I run the following command inside my function ...

```
openssl req -x509 -days $days -new -nodes -${hashCipher} -subj $csrSubject -passin file:${passwordFile} -key $rootCaKeyPath -out $rootCaCertPath
```

... I get the following error message.

Where ..

`$days` is passed in as an argument to a function.

[image]

No other variable substitutions are causing a problem.

The general openssl manual says that the `-days n` options requires an interger (but, I do not think they mean a bash integer datatype). The command works fine from the prompt, it's executing it in a shell script seems to trip things up.

I tried running the raw `openssl req` command with all of the desired command options' arguments spelled out explicitly. I even used delclare -i to directly specify an integer. Nothing seems to work inside the function. Same error. Very frustrating.

Any ideas?

Comment: What value are you passing for `$days`? Can you post the whole function with arguments>

Comment: Suffice it to say that the function is nothing more than the command above with parameters defined accordingly. I cannot post the function. There is something about using `openssl req` with the `-x509` and `-days $numberOfDays` that it does not like. It would be interesting to use updated versions of the command to see what happens.

Comment: @Inian I have passed many values for $days, from 30 to 3650. No dice, when I run this command inside of my function. No, it is not an input problem to the function. The command, written out fully, works at the command line.

Comment: I recommend putting `set -x` before this line in the script, so bash will print what *it* thinks the equivalent command is. My bet is there's something different from what you're executing by hand, and this should make the difference visible. P.S. my guess, without knowing anything about the rest of the situation, is that you have some Windows-style data (maybe from an internet download?) with invisible carriage return characters messing things up. If `set -x` prints something like `... -days $'365\r' ...` then this is what's causing it.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Hi. Your `set -x` idea is a wonderful one. Why the `-days` option would be the only one with a problem is a mystery, indeed. I will let you know.

Comment: @GordonDavisson `set -x` did it. It revealed that one of the arguments to my function was actually empty, which threw the whole thing off. Post an answer, you deserve some points!